# Tomcat image load fail

Tags: image, tomcat, load

Tomcat can't load images after I renamed the folder where the images are.
I have no idea what is wrong..

Please help me..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post more details on what you've tried so far and your current settings/code? Avoid posting screenshots. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the specific rule, because it's my first time to ask in stack overflow. 
And I was sure that my code wasn't wrong, but it was a server problem or others. That's why I didn't attach my code. Thank you for the information. I will read it, and I will make a good question next time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I've solved it.
The problem was url-pattern in web.xml
I wrote  '/*'  but it should be '*.jsp'
If you wrote /* like this,
tomcat will include JSP files to every file, even if it's an image file.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjEKy.png)